Multiple projects in a .NET8.0 solution, execute a script ONLY once before build
We have a solution having 6 csproj projects inside.
I need to run a dotnet format script on solution(not projects) level before build starts using Directory.Build.props.like:
  <Target Name="FormatSolution" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(HasFormattedSolution)' != 'true' ">
    <Exec Command="dotnet format --verbosity diagnostic $(SolutionDir)InfoExchange.sln" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <HasFormattedSolution>true</HasFormattedSolution>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

I tried other approaches in other questions and answers
such as: How do I call my script before all the builds for only once in a multi-targeting project
But like inserting a message like this:
  <Target Name="PrintTestMessage" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Test Message: Executing before build" />
    <PropertyGroup></PropertyGroup>
    <HasPrintedMessage>true</HasPrintedMessage>
  </Target>

Will execute at least 6 times based on 6 projects
Is there a good way to just run a dotnet format script only once on a solution level before build starts?
Before I tried to run the script on each project by searching .csproj file, but there were other problems due to another script to be running..so the solution wide script running is better.

See this answer for one way to do this

The short answer at the end of the day is, changed the solution .sln file to each project .csproj file, so that each project will only run once.
